# Load script before document load in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile, oauth

I'm trying to address the issue with Facebook OAuth and jQuery Mobile as described at the bottom of http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html .

On a registration page I have a "Sign in with Facebook" button. When I click the button I get a "Page Load Error".

Added to the registration page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="register">
  <script>
    $("#register").live('pageinit',function() {
      if (window.location.hash == "#_=_")
        window.location.hash = "";
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

but that didn't help - still same problem. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: please add ur script in document.ready function..

Comment: According to http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html the 'pageinit' event should be used instead of document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but this was a red herring. The script was actually working. The "Page Load Error" issue was due JQM expecting ajax page load, when it wasn't. Adding `data-ajax="false"` to the link solved the problem. This is explained in http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html.

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be run you need to load it *before* any jQueryMobile is loaded, at least according to the documentation. And from the code snippet I think this is loaded after your import of the jQM sources.

Your `<head>` should look something like this

```
<head>
    ...
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#register").live('pageinit',function() {
          if (window.location.hash == "#_=_")
            window.location.hash = "";
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
```

Edit: However, if you are loading the next page with AJAX and the part in the `<head>` is not reloaded, you can bind to the [`mobileinit` event](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) on the page *before* the pagewhere you want to remove the `#_=_`. I.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('mobileinit',function() {
      if (window.location.hash == "#_=_")
        window.location.hash = "";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My understanding from http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html is that nothing in `<head>` will run, which is why I used `data-role=page` (per the recommendations in the link above).

Comment: It depends on how the page is loaded. If you enter the page through an AJAX load from jQM, it only loads that part with `data-role=page`. Otherwise it just loads the entire page. I will update my answer with another method.